# Good Low Noise Long Exposure Astrophotography camera?

Tags: noise-reduction

Recommendations:

I was reading that Canons were the best at low noise long exposure photographs. Then I found this site, https://www.brendandaveyphotography.com/more/long-exposure-sensor-testing/

It seems to say that some Fuji cameras are better at low noise (half the noise) than Canon for 5 minuite exposures. Which is better Canon or Fuji?

Comparing cannon EOS 60d vs fujifilm X E1 on a second site: https://www.photonstophotos.net/Charts/RN_ADU.htm
Seems to suggest that the fuji has half the noise. Why don't I see reccomendation s for Fuji cameras as used for astrophotography?

Comment: The way some cameras get such good low noise numbers is by doing on-die analog noise reduction. This tends to not only eliminate noise, but also dim point sources of light (such as very dim stars) along with the noise. Such sensors are sometimes called ["star eaters"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94391/15871). I know not if the Fuji X-E1 is such a camera, but the reason many astro specialists like Canon is because, at least until very recently (*i.e.* EOS R5, R6, etc.) Canon didn't do much analog NR.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What should I look for in a camera for shooting in bulb mode for astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94391/15871)

Comment: Also related: [What should I look for in a camera for Night Sky Photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/113114/15871) and [What lens characteristics are important in star photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43114/15871)

Comment: Re: the link at Brendan Davey Photography: Taking images with the body cap on is a poor way to test camera performance. You're not measuring signal-to-noise ratio when there's no signal (light) involved whatsoever. Depending on the camera's processing engine, it may increase the amplification of the noise because it is the only (false) information coming from the sensor.

Comment: The first note from the Photons to photo link: **"These raw values are not appropriate for comparing camera models because they are not adjusted for gain or area."** In other words, these numbers are only appropriate for comparing different ISO settings for the *same camera*.

Comment: https://petapixel.com/2016/07/08/comparing-sensor-noise-top-cameras/

Comment: The Petapixel article you linked is directly based on Brendan Davey's flawed method. If the Fuji is eliminating all analog signals below a certain threshold before digitizing it, it will also eliminate a lot of dim stars because it also sees them as noise. [This Petapixel article](https://petapixel.com/2017/05/04/star-eater-issue-no-longer-recommend-sony-cameras-astrophotography/) illustrates the issue using Sony sensors, but Sony is not only one that does this. You've been warned. Do with it what you will.

Comment: Every time one of the "star eater" cameras is updated, the manufacturer will claim they've fixed it. Then real astrophotographers will [show that it hasn't been fixed.](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4278761)

Comment: At least [some Fuji cameras do it, too.](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4416122)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I look for in a camera for Night Sky Photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/113114/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-camera-for-night-sky-photography)